# Flutter password validator is never called using StreamTransformer

Tags: flutter, dart

### The issue

I'm using the `BLoC` pattern to validate `TextFields`.

For that I'm using `StreamController` class to `sink` and `listen` to the streams.

Although , the `Validator` is never called.

### Classes & Widget

This is my `validator` class

```dart
class Validators {
final validatePassword = StreamTransformer<String,String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (password,sink)
    {
      if(password.length > 4)
        {
          sink.add(password);
        }else{
          sink.add('Password must be atleast 5 characters');
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Then I'm building the `BLoC` class

```dart
class Bloc with Validators{
 final _passwordController = StreamController<String>();
 Function(String) get addPasswordStream => _passwordController.sink.add;
 Stream<String> get getPasswordStream => _passwordController.stream.transform(validatePassword);
}
final bloc = Block ()
```

And adding it to my `Cusotm Widget` by using the `StreamBuilder` class

```dart
  Widget passwordField(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.getPasswordStream,
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          return TextField(
            onChanged: bloc.addPasswordStream,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'password',
                labelText: 'password',
                errorText: snapshot.error
            ),
          );
        },
    );
  }
```

I've implemented the same method for the `email` validator and it works , but for some reason when I'm implementing it to the password `TextField` as well, it doesn't. I've used `flutter clean` and `flutter run` nothing changed. What have i completely missed ?

Comment: if you use `snapshot.error` where is `sink.addError` called then? or i miss something here?

Comment: i completely missed that on the validator, thank you, works fine now